# Is there something like AlarmManager(Android) in WindowsPhone7 mango, which will launch the app when the alarm goes off?

Tags: android, windows-phone

Is there something like AlarmManager(Android) in WindowsPhone7 mango, which will launch the app when the alarm goes off ?
Like in android we have http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html
But in WindowsPhone7 we have this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202965(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way for an application to be started in Windows Phone 7 is in response to a user action.

These include:
- launching from the application list
- launching from a live tile
- launching by tapping on a toast message sent for/from that app
- launching by tapping on the UI displayed from a reminder created by that app

Comment: Thanks. That helps. I hope they provide functionality like AlarmManager(Android) in next version.

Answer (score 0):

No.
you can't execute a app by time only when the user taps on a notification

Comment: Can you be more elaborative ?